# How to set description in facebook share dialog(what's on your mind?)

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using facebook sdk to share details to facebook and it works fine. Now my question, is there a way to set description to "What's on your mind?" text field.

[image]

Comment: I'm not an android guru. That usually called as  PlaceHolder.

Please try to do like this  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221072/android-add-placeholder-to-edittext)

Comment: Hi Suresh, thank you for quick reply, but that's not what i'm looking for. Actually when we share something to facebook in android the facebook app shows the above screen and allows the user to type something in "What's on your mind?" text field. Along with that it also shows the details what we passed to facebook app in template format(you can see one image and text called "abcd"), so i would like to show this text "abcd" directly in "What's on your mind?" text field instead of showing it in template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Feed Dialogs (deprecated)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0) used to have a `message` parameter earlier, but facebook removed. Also, there's no way to pre-populate the message in the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog).

They have removed this purposely in the UI Dialogs. If you are posting a feed using the [**API**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed#pubfields) (not dialog), then only you can populate the message with `message` parameter.

The `abcd` text is the description of the link that you (or the link admin) have provided; but the message is related to user and in case of dialogs, facebook expects that the user himself should give any message if he wants to, it should not be app-written.