# How to clear the string in the editText when clicking on it

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-edittext

I really wish that you can help me. I my application in Android to clear or erase the the default string assigned to the editText object on the main Activity when clicking on it, only if the value is equal to this text "Enter a message here", which I assigned it in the R.java file as "R.string.editTextOnStart". Here's the code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        editText.setText(R.string.editTextOnStart);

        textView.setText(R.string.textViewString);

        //if(editText.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(R.string.editTextOnStart))) {

            editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    text = editText.getText().toString();

                    if(text.equals(R.string.editTextOnStart)) {
                        editText.getText().clear();
                    }
                }
            });
        //}
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing that, you can specify the following using `hint`

In your layout xml file , under your `EditText`, add this

```
android:hint="Enter your text here"
```

This will appear on your edit text when you start the activity and disappears when user have clicked on it

Comment: Thanks Vidya Sagar and ShivBuyya, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Better make "Enter a message here" as hint in layout

```
android:hint="Enter a message here"
```

Comment: Thanks Vidya Sagar and ShivBuyya, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is almost perfect, however the issue is that you are comparing the variable `text` which is a String directly to `R.string.editTextOnStart` which is an int. To get the actual value you assigned to `R.string.editTextOnStart` you need to use the method `[Context.getString(R.string.editTextOnStart)][1]`. So your code should look like:

```
...
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
   text = editText.getText().toString();

   if(text.equals(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.editTextOnStart))) {
     editText.setText("");
   }
 }
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Java

```
setHint()
```

-or-

XML

```
android:hint=""
```

See [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221072/android-add-placeholder-text-to-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your onclick listener

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.yoursXmlId)).setText("");
```

Or set the text hint in your XML layout

```
android:hint="Enter Name"
```